# Column spacing on calculator

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pycharm

i've just started coding and have been writing a script for a calculator using python3 tkinter and I can't seem to get the columns to sit next to each other nicely.

[Calculator layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Mb4.png)

```
e = Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

button_1 = Button(root, text='1', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 = Button(root, text='2', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 = Button(root, text='3', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 = Button(root, text='4', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 = Button(root, text='5', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 = Button(root, text='6', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 = Button(root, text='7', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 = Button(root, text='8', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 = Button(root, text='9', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(9))
button_0 = Button(root, text='0', padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(0))
button_add = Button(root, text='+', padx=40, pady=20, command=button_add)
button_equal = Button(root, text='=', padx=91, pady=20, command=button_equal)
button_clear = Button(root, text='Clear', padx=79, pady=20, command=button_clear)

button_subtract = Button(root, text='-', padx=41, pady=20, command=button_subtract)
button_multiply = Button(root, text='*', padx=39, pady=20, command=button_multiply)
button_divide = Button(root, text='/', padx=39, pady=20, command=button_divide)

button_1.grid(row=3, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3, column=2)

button_4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=2)

button_7.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1, column=2)

button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)
button_add.grid(row=5, column=0)
button_equal.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2)
button_clear.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

button_subtract.grid(row=6, column=0)
button_multiply.grid(row=6, column=1)
button_divide.grid(row=6, column=2)
```

I've have tried resizing them so all the buttons are equal but there's still a gap in-between the columns. This is all the code that is related to the looks of the calculator. Im using python 3 tkinter and pycharm for mac os, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add `sticky='ew'` to all `grid(...)` of buttons and set `padx=40` for all buttons as well.

Answer (score 1):

Set a `sticky` for every widget,in the end of your code,add this(When your GUI only have those widgets,I suggest you put all of your button in a `Frame`.And use `Frame.winfo_children()` to do that):

```
xxx
for i in root.winfo_children():
    i.grid(sticky="nwes")

root.mainloop()
```